# Is it possible to bypass USB access restriction placed by the Active Directory?

Tags: penetration-test, physical, usb-drive, usb

I've been tasked with an onsite engagement to see what I can find from one of their laptops. They have a policy in place to block USB access through the Active Directory, e.g. When you try to access the USB drive, you will get an access denied, see [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-disable-usb-drive-use-in-an-active-directory-domain/) for more information.

Is there any way to bypass this? Will tools like Bash Bunny still execute the payload, regardless if I can access it or not?

Comment: This post may have something: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65869/bypass-usb-gpo-with-iphone-and-probably-other-mobile

Answer (score 2):

If you can plug a keyboard in and it works, you can use a tool like a Rubber Ducky (I'm assuming the bash bunny is similar, but I haven't played with it.) The Rubber Ducky appears to the computer as a Human Interface Device (HID). Keyboards announce themselves to computers as HID devices and are in turn automatically recognized and accepted.

Comment: This probably won't work, as Windows will only accept a keyboard or mouse, not a Mass Storage device.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The Rubber Ducky impersonates a keyboard or mouse (Human Interface Device). It doesn't pop up as a mass storage device.

Comment: I think OP needs to exfiltrate something via USB mass storage device, or execute something from it, not simply connecting any device. I am yet to see any security policy blacklisting mouses and keyboards. As a HID impersonating a keyboard, Rubber Ducky cannot execute anything the user could not execute by hand.